# Reg file not working for windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003

quick and simple,

i have one reg file with the following content ( to include a file on  DEP ):

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"D:\somedir\some.exe"="DisableNXShowUI"
```

so even if i click twice or go via command line with regedit /s regfile.reg , it seens that the script didn't worked.

What im missing?

Comment: What does it not do?  Have you investigated at all?  If so, please advise.  You'll have to define not working in this case before anyone can answer.

Comment: well, i checked into the registry and i cant find what i tried to insert via reg file over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My XP machine reg files show Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 instead of REGEDIT4. Where did you get REGEDIT4 from? I suggest you configure it manually and then export that key. That way, you have a proper reg file.

Comment: that's a good idea, let me check it out.

Comment: that solved my problem =) , i should use c:\\, instead c:\ on the .reg file